# Angular1.3: Access functions from standard controllers, inside a view which uses controllerAs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, frontend, angularjs-controller

I have a simple controller defined in my main app.js file, which controls opening/closing of my navbar and is visible on all other views of my app:

app.js:

```
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.menuActive = false;

  $scope.toggleMenu = function(){
    $scope.menuActive = !$scope.menuActive;
  }
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<nav class="side-menu"  ng-class="{ 'side-menu-open' : menuActive }">
    <ul>
      <li>LINK1</li>
      <li>LINK2</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!--Other views::.....-->
<div ui-view></div>
```

All my other views(which use controllerAs), have a button with an ng-click which I am using to access the above $scope.toggleMenu() function and ng-class, but this does not work, and I don't get any errors either:

view1.html :

```
<span class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="toggleMenu()">
    MENU
</span>
```

View1.js:

```
angular
 .module('myApp.view1', [])

 .controller('View1Ctrl', [
      function(){
      ................
       }
    ]);
```

Also, the reason I have done it this way again is because my navbar is persistent throughout my app. Does this go against best practices by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `.. controller as ..` syntax, make sure that you are using it for all controllers. Don't be selective about it.

Next, when using the syntax, you need not inject the `$scope` object. You need to instead use the `this` variable and attach any properties or functions that you would normally associate with the `$scope` object with the `this` object instead.

Thus,

```
$scope.toggleMenu = function(){
    $scope.menuActive = !$scope.menuActive;
}
```

becomes

```
this.toggleMenu = function(){
    this.menuActive = !this.menuActive;
}
```

Finally in your view, be sure to associate each expression with a controller.

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as main">
    <nav class="side-menu"  ng-class="{ 'side-menu-open' : main.menuActive }">
        <ul>
            <li>LINK1</li>
            <li>LINK2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view>
        <!-- Assuming that the following gets compiled to ui-view -->
        <span class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.toggleMenu()">
            MENU
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get some further hints on using the `controller as` syntax [here](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)